# Date pattern analysis in java

Tags: java, regex, date, simpledateformat

My requirement is to analyse a given date and find out its pattern like below:

> 21/12/2014 - dd/mm/yyyy
>
> 21.12.14 - dd.mm.yy
>
> 21-6-14 - dd-m-yy
>
> 2014/12/15 - yyyy/mm/dd

and so on like these.

So what sholud be my approach and why:

> 1. Validate the dates using regex and then print the pattern.
>
> or
>
> 2. Parse the date using SimpleDateFormat and then print the pattern.

Any other approaches are welcomed.

Comment: Here you are killing your thinking ability I guess. you can come up with your own solution it will really help you. You are going to buy someone's idea.

Comment: So.. what is the format of 02/04/11 ? it can be all permutations... You need some  boundary constraints.

Comment: If you have the possibility to get the information from the source, what format they are creating, it's the best way to start. Think about all the edge cases as `01-02-03` -> 01.Feb.2003, 02.Jan.2003, 03.Feb.2001, ...

Comment: Naive approach for first 3... `\d{2}[/.-]\d{1,2}[/.-]\d{2,4}`

Comment: I have my own solution and that's using regex and then printing the pattern. I have also thought of parsing the dates but it's becoming long. So my doubt is whether there is any performance related improvement in using date parser. Or any other solution where performance is improved as well as the code is reduced.

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\d+)([-./])\\d{1,2}\\2(\\d{2}(?:\\d{2})?)");

String date = "21/12/2014";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(date);
matcher.find();

boolean dayFirst = matcher.group(1).length() == 2;
boolean fourCharYear = true;
String separator = matcher.group(2);

String dateFormat = "1sepMMsep2".replace("sep", separator);

if(dayFirst) {
  dateFormat = dateFormat.replace("1", "dd").replace("2", "y");
  fourCharYear = matcher.group(3).length() == 4;
} else {
  dateFormat = dateFormat.replace("2", "dd").replace("1", "y");
}

if(fourCharYear) {
  dateFormat = dateFormat.replace("y", "yyyy");
} else {
  dateFormat = dateFormat.replace("y", "yy");
}

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
Date parse = format.parse(date);
```

It is based on the following assumptions:

1. First digit group is either the day or the year, the year will always be 4 characters if it comes first.
2. The separator will always be either `-`, `.` or `/`
3. The month will always come second
4. The year, when at the end, will always be either four or two digits.